# Rails injecting into validation method without overriding it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a problem with my validations in my Rails3 App. My App is based on a Rails 2 API which already has some basic validations for some fields like "price".

```
//Rails Backend API price.rb
validates_presence_of :price
```

Now if I work on the same model on my frontend Rails 3 App and add a custom validation it will override ALL the other validations defined in my backend application api.

```
// Rails Frontend App price.rb
class Price < ActiveResource::Base
validate :price_check
def price_check
    if self.price > self.old_price
      self.errors.add(:price, I18n.t('activerecord.errors.messages.price', :old_price => self.old_price))
    end
  end
```

I know I am overriding the validate method from my backend api and that's why the other validations are not working anymore - it's the same model - of course I do. Now how can I add validations without overriding the existent validations?
I tried some after_validation/before save but this isnt working either. I want to keep my validations from the api and add some more.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use project-specified validates)

```
validates :price_check, :if => :frontend_module?

def frontend_module?
  !!defined? FrontendApp # module name from application.rb
end
```

Comment: sorry, it's still using only the :price_check validation, not the backend validations. by using 'validate' all other validations are overriden

Comment: Ensure that " validate :price_check " placed after all others validators in frontend module ?

Comment: there are no other validations in this model.

Comment: Please, explain your problem more. This is a gist with my understanding:  https://gist.github.com/vitalyp/9426534

Comment: Maybe, you need Single Table Inheritance?

class Transaction < ActiveRecord
end

class CashTransaction < Transaction
end

class CreditCardTransaction < Transaction
    validates :settled, :presence => true
end

Comment: not really what I want to accomplish. I have: database <- API (model Price) with validations <- frontend app (model Price), also including views with other validations. Those are overriding the api application validations and I have to rewrite all of them in case I want to add a single one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49290/discussion-between-vitalyp-and-gulty)